# Modifying data from API and save in postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, fetch

I want to fetch some data from a public API and then modify this data. For example, I will add a Point(long, lat) in geography in Postgis. However, I need to fetch the data from a public API before I get there. I have tried this so far, but it doesn't seem like the logic makes sense.

Inserting data into the database works fine, and I have set it up correctly. However, the problems happen when I try to do it in a JSON function.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = express();
const db = require("./db");
app.use(express.json());

async function fetchDummyJSON(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        await db.query("INSERT INTO logictest(userId,id,title,completed) values($1,$2,$3,$4)",[json.userId+1,json.id,json.title,json.completed])
    });
}
fetchDummyJSON()


  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
  })
```

I keep getting SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top-level bodies of modules; however, fetchDummyData() is an async function from what I can tell. Is there a way to make more sense or make this work? I am going for a PERN stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function as well:

```
.then((json) => {
            await db.query("INSERT INTO logictest(userId,id,title,completed) values($1,$2,$3,$4)",[json.userId+1,json.id,json.title,json.completed])
        });
```

try

```
.then(async (json) => {
        await db.query("INSERT INTO logictest(userId,id,title,completed) values($1,$2,$3,$4)",[json.userId+1,json.id,json.title,json.completed])
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but do you know of a smarter way to do this?